# Delete Contacts in salesforce throws error using Developer console >> DEbug >> open execute anonymous window

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to delete **contacts** that match certain conditions, example if `Email = null OR Email = ''`, using Developer console >> DEbug >> open execute anonymous window,

```
List<Contact> contacts = [
        SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Email = null OR Email = ''
        LIMIT 742
    ];
    
    // To see the results before deletion, loop through the contacts and print their details
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        System.debug('Contact Id: ' + c.Id + ', FirstName: ' + c.FirstName + ', LastName: ' + c.LastName + ', Email: ' + c.Email);
    }
    
    // Delete the contacts that meet the specified conditions
    delete contacts;
```

but it throws an error

Line: 14, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003EX0003tMiQYAU; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete m***@.com could not be completed because it is associated with the following portal users.:m@***.com : []

What is wrong here, how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This Contact has been "promoted" to an Experience Cloud user (also known as "community" or "portal"). You can't delete users in SF but you can unlink them, maybe even obfuscate user details.

You should have a "Disable Portal User" button on the contact, click it. (if it's not there - check the page layout editor)

It's dangerous, irreversible (you can "promote" the contact to portal user again but it'll be a new user. You'll need unique username, the audit history like records created by that guy will not be linked etc), maybe try it out in a sandbox first.

Or if you're after mass solution - something like this should be a decent start

```apex
List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name, Username
FROM User
WHERE Contact.Email IN ('', null)];
for(User u : users){
    System.debug(u);
    u.IsPortalEnabled=false;
}
update users;
```

you will be able to delete these contacts afterwards.